# Why can we interchange "primes" and "irreducibles" in the definition of UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, definition, unique-factorization-domains

On Wikipedia, UFD is defined as an integral domain in which every element can be uniquely factored as product of primes (irreducibles), up to multiplication by units and arrangement.

My question is about why *primes* or *irreducibles* can be interchangeably placed in definition. I mean, in other words, are following two definitions equivalent?

> (1) $R$ is an integral domain in which every element can be uniquely factored as product of **primes** (up to unit multiplication and permutation).
>
> (2) $R$ is an integral domain in which every element can be uniquely factored as product of **irreducibles** (up to unit multiplication and permutation).

(from comments below, my question actually boils down to following:)

*If in a domain, every element can be uniquely factored into product of primes, then certainly it can be decomposed into irreducibles; how can we ensure uniqueness into irreducible factorization?*

Comment: Yes, it turns out that if all elements can be unique factored into irreducibles, then all irreducibles are primes. Basically, one mimics the proof for the integers as far as I recall.

Comment: How is proof of this? (In any integral domain, primes are irreducibles. )

Comment: Do you know the proof that irreducible integers are prime?

Comment: means, you are asking question in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes, do you know how to show that the irreducible elements in $\mathbb{Z}$ are prime, given that integers factor uniquely?

Comment: Yes in UFDs, irreducible implies prime.  The proof can be an analogy of a proof of Euclid's Lemma.

Comment: yes, in $\mathbb{Z}$ irreducible is prime. Suppose we define UFD by (1) (as in Herstein). Then in UFD, every irreducible is prime,  so decomposition into primes exists, and finally since primes are irreducibles also, so decomposition into primes is unique, soe definition (2). How about (2) implies (1)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume property (1); since any prime is irreducible, you have property (2).

Assume $R$ satisfies property (2). We want to see that any irreducible is prime, so also property (1) is satisfied.

Let $a$ be irreducible and suppose $a\mid bc$, so $bc=ad$ for some $d\ne0$ (the case when $bc=0$ is trivial). Decompose $b$, $c$ and $d$ into a product of irreducibles:
\begin{align}
b&=b_0b_1b_2\dots b_m && \text{$b_0$ invertible, $b_i$ irreducible for $1\le i\le m$} \\
c&=c_0c_1c_2\dots c_n && \text{$c_0$ invertible, $c_i$ irreducible for $1\le i\le n$} \\
d&=d_0d_1d_2\dots d_p && \text{$d_0$ invertible, $d_i$ irreducible for $1\le i\le p$} 
\end{align}
By assumption (2), we deduce that $a=ub_i$, for some $i$ and some invertible $u$, or $a=vc_j$, for some $j$ and some invertible $v$.

In the former case, $a\mid b$; in the latter case, $a\mid c$. Therefore $a$ is prime.

Comment: egreg, Thank you very much for your nice answer.